# xmonad: how to use clock applet to display time

Tags: gnome, xmonad, applet

I am using xmonad / haskell.

when I start nm-applet for wifi, I have a small icon on the top lef
then displays wifi reception.

Next to it I would like to to have a CLOCK / time display.

is there a (clock) gnome applet similar to nm-applet that works as a clock? (in xmonad?)

I searched for some time and tried some clock applets but I couldn't get it working.
Thanks for any help on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I think you really want is [XMobar](http://projects.haskell.org/xmobar/). You can still run nm-applet in the background but it gives you all sorts of good info too:

Here is an example of a highly customised bar at the top of the screen. You may have to open the image in a new tab to fully appreciate the top bar.
[image]

So just give it an install and I am sure that you will like it.

Comment: cool. do you have somewhere you configuration file for xmobar?

Comment: XMobar has its own config file which should exist in the ~/.xmonad directory. But you can call XMobar to start from your xmonad config in the way that it is done in xmonad-contrib: http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Hooks-DynamicLog.html#1

Comment: I just realised that the top bar in the image is actually using dzen2 to give you that but use XMobar. It is better.